# What does this error means and how to fix it?

Tags: python

I was creating a little bmi calculator in Python 3.5.1, but weirdly it doesn't work. In Python 2.7 it was working, but it isn't working here. My code is:

```
print ('Geef uw gewicht in kg: ')
gewicht_kg = input()
print ('Geef uw lengte in meters: ')
lengte_meters = input()
bmi = gewicht_kg / (lengte_meters * lengte_meters)
```

The string are written in Dutch, but that doesn't matter. If I run the program, the input does work (so I can type whatever I want) but when it suppose to make the calculation, it gives the following error:

```
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say you are now running this on Python 3. Which means your input should be `int(input())`. Also, for your python 2 code you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`, which then means for python 2 you should have `int(raw_input())`

Comment: @idjaw oh forgot to say, but I'm programming in Python 3.5.1. The input does work, but the calculation doesn't work. Then it says that I got a ''can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' '' error.

Comment: Update your original question with relevant information and up to date code. Don't put it in comments

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that Python is trying to multiply a list of characters with a string value, which makes no sense. Indeed: Your input is string (and should be entered unquoted), so it must be translated into a numeric format first.

Use

```
gewicht_kg = float(raw_input())
```

and similar for the other input and it will work out better.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.1, so that doesn't work. From an earlier question I found out that I got to use input(), and that worked.